# Правильно ли употреблено двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

В ранних публикациях: № 1 (27), № 2 (28), № 3 (29) сообщалось о создании концептуально нового исполнения затвора дискового поворотного с приведением описания и изложением основной сути изобретения.

Интересует вот что: можно ли здесь так употребить двоеточие? Не нужно ли никаких знаков после него? Скобками заменить нельзя, т.к. получаются двойные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ранних публикациях: № 1 (27), № 2 (28), № 3 (29)  - сообщалось о создании концептуально нового исполнения затвора дискового поворотного с приведением описания и изложением основной сути изобретения.

Это обычное оформление предложений с однородными членами и обобщающим словом.